# Garageband additional software download status in Mac

Tags: macos, garageband

Where Can I see about the Garageband additional software download status, when it got opened for the first time? And how to stop it manually?

version detail:
mac os high sierra 10.13.4
garageband 10.3.0

update:
I was thinking, if there might be a window/option where we could see the status of download and can pause or stop in that window itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GarageBand app does the download (spinning up a com.apple.MAContentInstallation helper process), so to stop it - save your work in any open app documents and quit the app.

You should have been notified of this like so:

[image]

The downloads go to your user library, but before trying to clean that out - what happens if you reopen the app and watch the dialogs and/or see the options in the GarageBand menu Sound Library sub menu?

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, i tried quitting the app to stop the download it works, but i was thinking there might be a window/option where we could see the status of download and can pause or stop in that window itself, so that i can prevent closing application while working on it.

Comment: Did you log out the user in the Mac or just reboot? Then you should have a better notification @raj

Comment: I just did cmd+q for quitting the garageband application.

Comment: I would log out and then perhaps reboot. Next time you start garageBand - does it prompt you @Raj

Comment: it does prompt @ cmd+q also. I think I got my answer, that there is no window like the download manager, where we could start/pause downloads as required.